# list literal and list comprehension behaving differently

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a very strange issue with Python 3.7. Specifically, I have a function that takes a list of document IDs, and returns the wikipedia documents they correspond to. What's strange is that, if I pass in a list comprehension as I want to do, it returns nothing, but if I pass in a list literal with the exact same values, it somehow works. Note that this is using pdb, in the interactive prompt it opens when you type `interact`:

If I run the list comprehension, I get this list:

```
>>> [x[0] for x in truncated]
[3553957, 4480571, 4686346, 1955046, 4476254, 4510002, 3941950, 2991560, 5314256, 3949007]
```

If I run the query with this list literal, it works (data truncated for brevity):

```
>>> self._db.query_ids([3553957, 4480571, 4686346, 1955046, 4476254, 4510002, 3941950, 2991560, 5314256, 3949007])
[(1955046, 'Hairy_nightshade', 'Hairy nightshade is a common name for...')]
```

But if I combine the two expressions, it returns nothing:

```
>>> self._db.query_ids([x[0] for x in truncated])
[]
```

The actual function that's being called has no side effects, it just queries a database, so it doesn't change between calls in any way:

```
def query_ids(self, ids):
    """
    Returns the tokens for each document with the given ID
    """
    result = self.conn.execute(
        'SELECT doc_id, document, group_concat(tokens, " ") FROM doc WHERE doc_id in ({}) GROUP BY doc_id'.format(
            ', '.join(['?'] * len(ids))), ids)
    data = result.fetchall()
    return data
```

How is this possible?

---

If I add a `print(ids)` to the first line of my `query_ids` function, the list of IDs is printed identically both times, but it still doesn't work with the list comprehension:

```
(Pdb) self._db.query_ids([x[0] for x in truncated])
[3553957, 4480571, 4686346, 1955046, 4476254, 4510002, 3941950, 2991560, 5314256, 3949007]
[]
(Pdb) self._db.query_ids([3553957, 4480571, 4686346, 1955046, 4476254, 4510002, 3941950, 2991560, 5314256, 3949007])
[3553957, 4480571, 4686346, 1955046, 4476254, 4510002, 3941950, 2991560, 5314256, 3949007]
[(1955046, 'Hairy_nightshade', 'Hairy nightshade is a common name for several plants and may refer to...')]
```

Comment: If I do a `def fn(x): return x` and call x as a list, or output of a list comprehension I get the list back , so something else might be going on, could you `print(ids)` in your function? And even the string inside `execute` seems to be the same for both cases

Comment: Yep I added a print statement and the function prints out the list of IDs in both cases, but only fails in the list comprehension case

Comment: Wild guess: `truncated` is a generator of some sort, you consumed all of its elements doing the list comprehension, so there were no elements left when you did the query.

Comment: Can it be related to https://bugs.python.org/issue21161? This looks more like a pdb issue...

Comment: `truncated` isn't a generator, but it is a slice: `truncated = sort[0:n]`

Comment: Although notably, truncated is a list of numpy types, not native python types: `type(truncated[0][1])`, `<class 'numpy.float64'>`

Comment: Please do not tag a question `pdb` because you used `pdb` as part of trying to figure out the problem. Use it when you have a question *about using* `pdb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a strange bug, but I believe I've worked it out.

The issue wasn't the type of `truncated`, which was a list, but rather the contents of that list were numpy int64 types, *not* python integers:

```
(Pdb) !a = [x[0] for x in truncated]
(Pdb) type(a)
<class 'list'>
(Pdb) type(a[0])
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

When this list of `numpy.int64`s were passed into the database query, they were ignored, because the Python sqlite3 API doesn't know how to deal with non-native Python types: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#using-adapters-to-store-additional-python-types-in-sqlite-databases

> The following Python types can thus be sent to SQLite without any problem: None, int, float, str, bytes

Thus, when I converted the data into native Python integers, it worked:

```
(Pdb) self._db.query_ids([int(x[0]) for x in truncated])
[3553957, 4480571, 4686346, 1955046, 4476254, 4510002, 3941950, 2991560, 5314256, 3949007]
[(1955046, 'Hairy_nightshade', 'Hairy nightshade is a common name for several plants and may refer to ')]
```